# An issue with the loop in a code which keeps constantly re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, httprequest

React warns me that I have to add an "images" dependency but when I do that, it loops and shuts it all down. Is there something I can do to "images" so they don't change every render?

```
const App = () => {
  const [imageName, setImageName] = useState('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(Status.IDLE);
  const [isShowBtn, setIsShowBtn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!imageName) {
      setStatus(Status.IDLE);
      setImages([]);
      setIsShowBtn(false);
    }

    if (imageName !== '' || page > 1) {
      setStatus(Status.PENDING);

      fetchImages(imageName, page)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          const imagesValue = images.concat(data.hits);

          setImages(
            imagesValue.map(({ id, webformatURL, largeImageURL }) => ({
              id,
              webformatURL,
              largeImageURL,
            }))
          );

          setIsShowBtn(data.totalHits > imagesValue.length);
          setStatus(Status.RESOLVED);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          setError(error);
          setStatus(Status.REJECTED);
        });
    }
  }, [imageName, page]);

const handleSearchSubmit = imageName => {
    setImageName(imageName);
    setPage(1);
  };

  const handleLoadMoreClick = () => {
    setPage(page => page + 1);
    setIsShowBtn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Searchbar onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit} />
      {status === Status.REJECTED && <p>Error: {error.message}</p>}

      <ImageGallery imageName={imageName} images={images} status={status} />
      {status === Status.PENDING && <Loader />}
      {isShowBtn && <Button onClick={handleLoadMoreClick} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to move "imagesValue" out somehow but it's just strictly influenced by the fetch. Besides, I moved the whole function of fetch to useEffect and called it there which didn't work.
Also, useMemo and useCallback were tried but also no fix has been occurred.

Comment: Do you **really** need to concatenate the newly retrieved images with the existing ones seeing that the new images are based on a different search parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Well... the rule of thumb here is that you always should have your "images" and your "status" as a dependency in your useEffect, whenever the useEffect actually changes it. For clearence, I switched "Status.PENDING" to "PENDING", "Status.IDLE" to "IDLE", and so on. Maybe there are underlying reasons for having it like so... it just seemed redundant.

Therefore, we need to tell React that it should skip fetchImages if the fetchImages fn has already been called and the promise has been fullfilled.

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState("IDLE"); //changed here


useEffect(() => {
    if (!imageName) {
        setStatus("IDLE");
        setImages([]);
        setIsShowBtn(false);
    }

    if (imageName !== '' || page > 1) {
        setStatus("PENDING");
    }
    
    if (status === "PENDING") { //notice what we did here to avoid multiple calls
        fetchImages(imageName, page)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                 // seems like you are mapping something to itself,
                 // so I removed the mapping function here.
                 // feel free to keep it in case you have something in mind to do it
                 setImages(images => [...images, data.hits]) 
                 // those functions from useState, so called reducers,
                 // can accept a callback fn with the current state and instead of using concat, I used the spread operator, but you should be the same results afterall. 
                 setIsShowBtn(data.totalHits > imagesValue.length);
                 setStatus("RESOLVED");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                setError(error);
                setStatus("REJECTED");
            });
         }}}, [images, setImages, status, imageName, page]);
```

The underlying ideia here is that if

```
imageName !== '' OR page > 1
```

we are setting status to PENDING. The useEffect will finish his turn there.
Than, since, status is on your dependency array, useEffect will be called again, this time status === "PENDING" will be true and we are going to fetch images.

When the promise is fullfilled, fetchImages will update the status to either "RESOLVED" or "REJECTED", therefore fetchImages will not be fired again.

If you have some time, read this article below
https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

This one helped me a lot to understand useEffect behavior.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you much, figured out now. Cheers!